# JQuery submit - infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to disable all elements which has style `display:none` before submitting the form.

If there is `e.preventDefault()`, the form is not submitted at all and if there is no `e.preventDefault()` the infinite loop occures.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(':input:hidden').length);
    $('#reservation-form > :input:hidden').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#reservation-form').unbind('submit').submit();

});
```

Do you know what to do to make all `display:none` fields disabled before submitting this form?

Comment: Your problem is that the event is not bound to the `#reservation-form` as you've delegated it to the `document`

Comment: I think it's because your listener is on `$(document)` and not on `#reservation-form`.

Comment: To pre-empt what may be potentially your next issue:  *disabled elements are not included in form submits*.  (could be that that's what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to run `$('#reservation-form').unbind('submit').submit();`

Remove the `e.preventDefault();` call and return true at the end of the function:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    console.log($(':input:hidden').length);
    $('#reservation-form > :input:hidden').attr("disabled", true);
    return true;
});
```

This should give you the behavior you want without having to bind and unbind events.

Comment: Wait, it makes sense!...  But the `return true;` statement is useless here

Comment: I like adding it, as far as I recall, returning false will prevent your form from submitting, so I rather return true explicitly.

Comment: Just tested it to make sure, and returning false does prevent your form from submitting (very useful for when doing validations before submitting)

Comment: Yes, `return false` to prevent the event continuing.  Anything other than return false to continue - so no return, return true, return "woohoo";  will continue

Answer (score 2):

You are binding event to `document` level, so to unbind `submit`, you should unbind it at `document` level too.

That's said, the easiest method is to call instead DOM native `submit()` event:

```
$('#reservation-form')[0].submit();
```

BTW, for boolean attribute, better is to use `.prop()` even if in your case, it change nothing:

```
$('#reservation-form > :input:hidden').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Now it submits, but I'm afraid that this does not work. Even wher there is prop, the fields which has currently display:none style are sent. I want all elements with display:none style not to be sent or at least to be empty.

Comment: Maybe you should use as selector: `$('#reservation-form  :input:hidden')`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong selector to get the elements with input type hidden.
You should be using :

```
$('input[type=hidden]')
```

Documentation : [Css Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: `:hidden` is a jQuery selector: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: oh my bad, i only used standard css selectors, thanks for pointing out, should i delete answer ?